# blinking cursor in firefox on snap and div elements

Tags: html, css, firefox

I want to imitate a read-only input field with span (so that it will adjust its width to accomodate whatever will be inside it). Simple div component:

```
<div tabindex='-1' contentEditable='false'>Please stop blinking</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bLTkw/

When I click on the div the blinking cursor pops up. It does not reproduce on chrome and IE. Typical firefox issue. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: try: `user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;`

Comment: Thanks. Another solution would be to press F7 in Firefox to turn off caret browsing mode. Just found it.

Comment: That's off by default, so you must have switched it on inadvertently at one time.